# Http Request in Android from the service

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-service, httprequest

I am trying to do a post Http request from Service not from Activity. This Service is already been set to be continuously call after 5 second with the help of timertask.

In this service I am sending http request which is throwing error `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`, I know why this error is thrown as I am sending http request from my main thread which is against android rules.

In Addition, I am aware I can use AsyncTask class, but the problem is AsyncTask class need to have UI thread which I do not have as I am in service.

May be another constraint I am having is the parent class is using calling this class in every 5 seconds so maybe some thread issue. Not sure.

So, can anybody suggest me some idea to perform  this task, I am not sure if I can use Handlers for it, if so please give me simple example as I am bit out of touch from android.

If you need my code snippet let me know, but it is very straight just json HTTP request using httpclient.

```
public abstract class Data extends TimerTask {

protected void request(JSONObject content) {

     Log.i(TAG, content.toString());
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://test.test.test/data.json");
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(measurement.toString());
        httpost.setEntity(se);
        httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        client.execute(httpost, responseHandler);
    }catch(IOException exception){
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Since a `TimerTask` is executed on a background thread, something is very wrong with your code. Please post the code and the complete stack trace.

Comment: here is the updated one

Comment: First, `Data` is an abstract class, which means that there is at least one other class that you do not have here, since you cannot create an instance of `Data`. Second, you did not post the stack trace.

Comment: yes, but I guess more imp is how to do the http request from here ....

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example from the android docs on [creating a background service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).The simplest way to accomplish what you're describing, a simple `HttpPost` from a background thread without using an `AsyncTask` is to use an `IntentService`.

```
public class BackgroundService extends IntentService {    

    @Override    
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {   
        Bundle extras = workIntent.getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
           //do work here
        }
    }

}
```

The basic idea is pretty simple. Once your service is regiestered in your mainfest, you can start it, and send any data you need to it, using an `Intent`.

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
startService.putExtra(stringMeasurmentToPost);
startService(startIntent);
```

This will broadcast the data to your `IntentService`, start it up, and perform whatever actions you need to on a background thread. If you're going to really be executing this every 5 seconds or so, you may way to look into using a regular service - not an intent service. The main difference between the two classes is that an `IntentService` will stop when it is finished doing whatever you will tell it to do, while a `Service` can remain active in the background so long as it is not killed by normal system processes. You can still send tasks to a `Service` using intents but the set up of a `Service` is slightliy more complicated than that of an `IntentService`.

Also - I would not use `TimerTask`. Rather I would use a `Handler` and `Runnable` combination with postDelayed() if you need to execute things repeatedly on a loop.

Comment: I was looking into this IntentService, but does not fit in well in my situation, but I do know If I can make it with work Handlers? what u say

Comment: You can to know if you can make it work with a handler? You can certainly use a handler/runnable combo instead of a TimerTask if that's what your asking. If an `IntentService` won't work what about a normal service or even an `AsyncTask`? Is there any specific reason these won't work?